# "SyntaxError: Unexpected token /" while loading json using angular

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to load simple json file into my application, however it is showing me the following error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token /
    at Object.parse (native)
    at fromJson (http://127.0.0.1:8080/angular/angular.js:1321:14)
    at defaultHttpResponseTransform (http://127.0.0.1:8080/angular/angular.js:10393:16)
    at http://127.0.0.1:8080/angular/angular.js:10484:12
    at forEach (http://127.0.0.1:8080/angular/angular.js:322:20)
    at transformData (http://127.0.0.1:8080/angular/angular.js:10483:3)
    at transformResponse (http://127.0.0.1:8080/angular/angular.js:11278:21)
    at processQueue (http://127.0.0.1:8080/angular/angular.js:15961:28)
    at http://127.0.0.1:8080/angular/angular.js:15977:27
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (http://127.0.0.1:8080/angular/angular.js:17229:28)VM2820 angular.js:13550 (anonymous function)VM2820 angular.js:10225 $getVM2820 angular.js:15969 processQueueVM2820 angular.js:15977 (anonymous function)VM2820 angular.js:17229 $get.Scope.$evalVM2820 angular.js:17045 $get.Scope.$digestVM2820 angular.js:17337 $get.Scope.$applyVM2820 angular.js:11572 doneVM2820 angular.js:11778 completeRequestVM2820 angular.js:11711 requestLoaded
app.js:52 undefined
```

controller.js:

```
.controller('PhoneDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
      function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('data1/projects.json').success(function(data) {
         // $scope.phone = data;
          console.log(data)
        }).error(function (data, status) {
            $scope.response = 'Request failed';
             console.log(status)
        });
      }])
```

project.json

```
{
  "projectName": "TDI – UI",
  "projectDetails": "Part of TDI team",
  "projectPeriod": "Dec 2014 – Till Date"
}
```

Comment: Post your JSON here.

Comment: The given JSON doesn't produce the error you mention.

Comment: did you check in the console that this is really what the webservice answer ?

Comment: This is resolved, ther was no problem, I just created same json file and deleted privious file and it worked, my be old one was corrupted???
Thanks